# Django model's string representation creates duplicates queries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Working on Airport API Service task. Can not solve N+1 problem for Flights:

**moldels.py:**

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, related_name="flights", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    airplane = models.ForeignKey(Airplane, related_name="flights", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    crew = models.ManyToManyField(Crew, related_name="flights")
    departure_time = models.DateTimeField()
    arrival_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["departure_time"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.route} ({self.departure_time})"
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class FlightListSerializer(FlightSerializer):
    route = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)
    airplane_name = serializers.CharField(source="airplane.name", read_only=True)
    tickets_available = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = (
            "id",
            "route",
            "airplane_name",
            "departure_time",
            "arrival_time",
            "tickets_available",
        )
```

**views.py:**

```
class FlightViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Flight.objects.all()
serializer_class = FlightSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAdminOrIsAuthenticatedReadOnly,)

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.queryset
    if self.action == "list":
        queryset = (
            queryset
            .select_related("airplane", "route__destination", "route__source")
            .annotate(
                tickets_available=(
                    F("airplane__rows") * F("airplane__seats_in_row")) - Count("tickets")
            )

        )
        return queryset

    return queryset

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == "list":
        return FlightListSerializer

    # if self.action == "retrieve":
    #     return TripDetailSerializer

    return FlightSerializer
```

**Problem:**

I checking endpoint with debug_toolbar and it shows [7 duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb3Uk.png).

Before it was much more, but I fixed some by add selected_related method and decrease it from 25 to 17.

I noticed, that this problem comes from "route" field.

**This is Route model:**

```
class Route(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(
        Airport,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="sources"
    )
    destination = models.ForeignKey(
        Airport,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="destinations"
    )
    distance = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["source", "destination"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.source.closest_big_city} - {self.destination.closest_big_city}"
```

String representation creates duplicates queries. So far it's just 10 duplicates, but each time I create new Route instance, I've got +2 ducolicate queries.

I know that one of the solutions, is just rewrite string representation method. But I need it like it is right no, so my question is how can I fix this N+1 problem?

Updated:
this is my Airport model:

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, validators=[validate_upper_case], unique=True)
    closest_big_city = models.CharField(max_length=65)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} (IATA code: {self.code}; city: {self.closest_big_city})"
```

Comment: Can you share the `Airport` model?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem added Airport model to question

Comment: Are you sure this is the `FlightViewSet` view? Based on the queries, I would say it is some sort of "listview" for `Route`s, the `SELECT ... FROM route LIMIT 1000` seems to say that, that there is thus some other queryset involved, not for the `Flight`s.

Comment: Normally you can see for a query *where* the queryset is defined that triggers this, thus making it more clear where the query originates from.

Comment: So yes, I noticed, this 10 duplicates come from Route model string representation. If I change in Route model def __str__(self) method to somthing like this: return str(self.distance), all this duplicates will go away, only left 7 queries. Questions is how to keep previouse string representation, but sovle N+1 problem? @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: well evidently it originates from the `__str__` but not from the queryset of the `Flight`s, but the one of the `Route`s, so you should inspect the `SELECT ... FROM _route LIMIT 100`...

Comment: In theory, this should be fixed my select_related method, because Flight with Route is ManyToOne relations. That is why in Flight def get_queryset(self) I used .select_related("airplane", "route__destination", "route__source"). It's decreased duplicate queries amount, but still for now there are 10 duplicates(as shown on screenshot). If add additional parameter "route" to select_related, it's just add +1 query, but didn't do anything to duplicates. If that what you mean? if not, maybe I not understand your point. Can you please explain it? @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: it has nothing to do with your `get_queryset` or `select_related`, since the `SELECT ... FROM route LIMIT 100` is never triggered if it would use a related model: in that case it would be `SELECT ... FROM route WHERE (!) ...`, hence there is something else that lists all routes. Likely the problem is the same if you would return `Flight.objects.none()` in the `get_queryset`.

Comment: I am using Django Rest Framework UI to check queries, could it be because my view is ModelViewset, so it's create on the same list page also table for create new Flight(method POST), and all this extra duplicates come from this create table? @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: well I would think it is the form that for example enables to create flights, that will make a dropdown with all routes, and that is likely causing the problem.

Comment: So in the end N+1 problem was caused by Django Rest Framework UI and if more specifically by create form. So for GET method I don't have any duplicate queries. Thank you for helping me figure this out! @Willem Van Onsem